# Plot map of towns showing rates of assaults

Tags: r, mapping, geospatial

I have a data (see below) showing the longitude and latitude of different towns. I want to plot a map of this town showing the number of assaults that occurred. The map will also show the label of each town and legend bar showing the rate of occurrence. Please any help will be greatly appreciated. I have tried the code below and have attached the figure with empty canvas.[image: plot map showing empty canvas]

```
 fg<-read.csv ("crimedata.csv")
 ##draw the map
 p<-ggplot(fg, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill=Assault)) +
 geom_polygon(color="grey")+
 coord_map("polyconic")
 p
```

Here is my data:

[Link to dataframe "crimedata.csv"](https://osf.io/3vj7a/)

Thanks

Comment: Hi Baz. The link doesn't link to your data I'm afraid. However, from looking at your plot, it seems that your problem is that your lat and long data are of character or factor type rather than numbers. Try `fg$long <- as.numeric(as.character(fg$long))` and `fg$lat <- as.numeric(as.character(fg$lat))` then re-running your plot code in the first instance.

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you for getting back to me on this. I changed the data type to numbers but the map is still not showing. Also, I have shared a link to my data. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs tidied up a bit before plotting. The steps are

1. Read in the csv
2. Remove rows with incomplete data
3. Remove the strange non-ascii characters that appear in your lat and long columns
4. Convert the lat and long columns from character to numeric
5. Most of the Locations are in a small cluster in the top right of your data. There are only two towns that are outside of this cluster, but plotting them means you cannot see the detail in the rest of your data, so you should filter these out by removing any location with a lat less than 50.
6. Some towns have duplicate entries. Presumably these need to be removed. The easiest way to do this is to group by Location and take the first entry (or the mean of the entries, which is equivalent since all fields are duplicated)
7. Plot with points using the number of rapes as the color aesthetic and a text label taken from the Location column

Putting all this together, we would have something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)

fg <- read.csv('crimedata.csv')

fg %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(fg)) %>%
  mutate(long = sub('\u00a0', '', long), lat = sub('\u00a0', '', lat)) %>%
  mutate(long = as.numeric(long), lat = as.numeric(lat)) %>%
  filter(lat > 50) %>%
  group_by(Location) %>%
  summarize(Rape = mean(Rape), lat = mean(lat), long = mean(long),
            group = mean(as.numeric(group))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(long, lat, color = Rape)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Location), color = 'gray50', nudge_y = -0.02,
            hjust = 0) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'green3', high = 'red3') +
  coord_map("polyconic") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Allan for your response and solution. However, I actually want to plot a map instead of points. Is this possible given the data provided? Cheers

Comment: @Baz this _is_ a map. The only features on it are the towns, since that's all you have in your data. What is it you were expecting to see? If you want to see regions, boundaries, coastlines etc then you will need specific map data for this.